# I set DOM elements' heights all to the same var, but they appear to have different heights?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I set all three elements to the same height var but each element is slightly bigger than the last. What is going on? The var is itemsh.

```
class LogoBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div style= {{ width: '100%', height: '80px', background: 'black'}}>
      <img src={mylogo} style={{marginLeft: '20%', float: 'left'}}/>
      <Login width='1200px' height='200px' bgc='black'/>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let h = parseInt(this.props.height.slice(0, this.props.height.length-2), 10);
  let mTop = Math.ceil(h / 10) + 'px';
  let fbh = Math.ceil(h*.8);
  let fbmTop = Math.ceil(fbh*.2);
  let flexboxheight = fbh + 'px';
  let flexboxmargtop = fbmTop + 'px';
  let itemsh = Math.ceil(fbh*.4) + 'px';

  return (
    <div style={{background: this.props.bgc, height: this.props.height, float: 'right', width: this.props.width}}>
      <button style={{float: 'right', marginRight: '30%', marginLeft: '5px', marginTop: mTop, height: itemsh}} onClick={()=>{return 1;}}>Login</button>
      <div style={{display: 'flex', height: flexboxheight, width: '180px', justifyContent: 'start', flex: '1', flexDirection: 'column', float: 'right', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginTop: mTop}}>
        <input type='text' value='password' style={{width: '175px', height: itemsh}}/>
        <a href='https://someotherplace.com' style={{marginTop: flexboxmargtop, height: itemsh}}>Forgot password?</a>
      </div>
      <input type='text' value='username' style={{float: 'right', marginRight: '5px', marginTop: mTop, width: '175px', height: itemsh, textHeight: itemsh}}/>
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

[image: Dating Site]

Comment: Sorry about the variable names and formatting. Never thought I would share the code. Food for thought.

Comment: Have you looked in an inspector? Are the heights actually the same? Maybe some padding/margins gone wrong?

Comment: No I have not, good idea. I'm a straight noob lol.

Comment: They are all height 64 but when I mouseover them I get different dimensions in the tooltip. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly set all padding to 'padding: "0px"' and they all appear the same. I guess default padding of elements is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Actually that didn't quite fix it. Later "flex-shrink" reared its head. I had to set flexShrink: '0' on the input inside of the flexbox.